# Multiple plots from function Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

(Adjusted to suggestions)
I already have a function that performs some plot:

```
def plot_i(Y, ax = None):
    if ax == None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax.plot(Y)
    plt.close(fig)
    return fig
```

And I wish to use this to plot in a grid for n arrays. Let's assume the grid is (n // 2, 2) for simplicity and that n is even. At the moment, I came up with this:

```
def multi_plot(Y_arr, function):
    n = len(Y_arr)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(n // 2, 2)
    for i in range(n):
        # assign to one axis a call of the function = plot_i that draws a plot
    plt.close(fig)
    return fig
```

Unfortunately, what I get if I do something like:

```
# inside the loop
plot_i(Y[:, i], ax = ax[k,j])
```

Is correct but I need to close figures each time at the end, otherwise I keep on adding figures to plt.
Is there any way I can avoid calling each time plt.close(fig)?

Comment: Not sure I understand what exactly you are looking for. But matplotlib has [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html) a good example of how to distribute `N` subplots in an `n x m` grid.

Comment: @Mr.T I already have a way to distribute the plots, this one is easier and I will implement it. However, checking the link, what id done for each ax is ax.plot. I wish to call my personal plotting function for each ax. Doing so, I would be able to call this multi_plot for different functions.

Comment: Pass `plot_i` an `ax` parameter and switch to the [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) within it.

Comment: @BigBen I tried, but still do not understand how to do this, could you explain with an example? I tried setting ax = None as parameter in plot_i, which if None get the current axis with plt.gca(). In the multi_plot function, I then pass the axis parameter as the axis of interest, but yet it prints each single plot and does not return a fig object that contains all of them. Will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @BigBen I actually solved the first issue, thank you for the clarification!!!

Comment: I don't see the need to create and close a figure in the first function, nor to close the figure in the second. Am I missing something?

Comment: @azelcer It is indeed strange. However if I do not close the figure it shows the plot in the cell every time, and I would like to avoid this and show it only once I call the variable in which I save the plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_i(Y, ax=None):
    if ax == None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot(Y)
    return

def multi_plot(Y_arr, function, n_cols=2):
    n = Y_arr.shape[1]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(n // n_cols + (1 if n % n_cols else 0), n_cols)
    for i in range(n):
        # assign to one axis a call of the function = plot_i that draws a plot
        function(Y_arr[:, i], ax = ax[i//n_cols, i%n_cols])
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.linspace(0,12.6, 100)
    # let's create some fake data
    data = np.exp(-np.linspace(0,.5, 14)[np.newaxis, :] * x[:, np.newaxis]) * np.sin(x[:, np.newaxis])
    fig = multi_plot(data, plot_i, 3)
```

Be careful when using `gca()`: it will create a new figure if there is no  figure active.